# call vim function with current word

Tags: vim

suppose I have a line like this: `hello foo bar`

and my cursor is on `foo`. I want to map a key that will call a function with `foo` without me having to first select it visually. How would I do this in vim?

Comment: Is it possible to bind a key to a macro?  If so, you could perform the select and then make the function call from the macro.

Comment: `iw` is the [text object selection](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#object-select) command to operate on a word without selecting it first. For example, `diw` will delete "foo", or `viw` will visually select "foo", regardless of your cursor position within "foo". Is it possible to use text object selection after the key mapped to your function? Then you could use your function with any text object command, e.g. `daw` deletes "foo " including trailing whitespace, or `das` deletes an entire sentence, or `di"` deletes everything within quotes regardless of cursor position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
nnoremap \print :echo printf('word under cursor: %s',expand('<cword>'))<CR>
```

Answer (score 4):

you are looking for function `expand(expression)`

here your expression would be `'<cword>'`

If you love to put it as function argument, you could :`yourFunction(expand('<cword>'))`

`:h expand(` for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution...

```
nnoremap <leader>f yw:call fun(@")<cr>
```

Better solution...

```
nnoremap <leader>f :call fun(<c-r><c-w>)<cr>
```

Comment: This would only work if the cursor was on the "f" of "foo", right?

Comment: it polluted the `"` register, it would be good practice to restore the original value after the function call.

Comment: I agree, overwriting `"`, or any register, is generally quick and dirty.  It's just another possible approach.